# Error in translating C++ to Python using R Studio Code

Tags: python, c++

Ok. For a question in my assignment I have to translate a C++ code into Python. I do not think it matters what particular code, but I have to test it using:

```
intmain(){
returnfac(9);
}
```

I think I may getting close, I just used Visual Studio Code with Python extension and used a code to get a factorial. After fixing a few other errors, I am stuck on an error that says Syntax error: unmatched '{'

Again, I think I may be close.

```
int n;
long factorial = 1.0;

cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> n;

    if (n < 0)
        cout << "Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.";
    else {
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        cout << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was just expecting output to give something like:
Enter a positive integer: 8
Factorial of 8 = 40320

However, I have a feeling that maybe I should rewrite it based on the 2nd line of code given in the question: returnfac(9);

Any advice is greatly appreciated, John

Comment: My advice when it comes to translations is (as always): ***Don't*** translate code. Instead *reimplement* the algorithm in the target language.

Comment: The only real way, learn both languages (good enough). Then understand the algorithm in the first language (if needed write some unit tests using the original algorihm). Rewrite the code in the other language (and run the tests on those to see if results match). Languages are different enought that details matter and 1-1 line converion will (usually) not work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude than you for the timely response. Can I ask what you mean by  reimplementing? I basically got what I needed to work today, and it will suffice no worries for my assignment. Unfortunately the DSc program that I am in is very hands off and the professor for this Compiler Design course is VERY hands off. What still bother me is that I am not sure if Visual Studio Code is an "interpreter" or maybe, I just used it as one?, because the question emphasized using an interpreter and not a compiler. Nonetheless, thank you for your timely response, John

Comment: @PepijnKramer than you for the response. I would love to do it the correct way, but unfortunately I do not have time. The DSc program I am in is very hands off and the professor especially for this Compiler Design course is especially VERY hands off.  It is an online DSc program in CS and although Iove it, the courses are 8 weeks long, and I am working full-time, and doing RNA-seq analysis (for colleagues[I am also a molecular biologist]) and developing an eTutoring Company.  I got it to work today ad what I did will suffice for an answer. Anyways, thanks for your help, John

Comment: Instead of using the original code, translating it into the target language, you instead figure out what the original code is doing. Then you take that description and throw away the original code, to write a brand new program in the target language, using only the description.

Comment: Direct translations between languages usually don't turn out well, it doesn't matter if it's for programming, spoken or written languages. For example, Python have many data-structures built-into the language itself that C++ doesn't, and the same with a lot of standard modules that doesn't have any corresponding facility in the C++ standard library (they need third-party libraries in C++). By doing a direct translation from C++ to Python, you might not use all the good Python modules, or using the most [Pythonic](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/p/pythonic.htm) idioms.

Comment: It is well intended advice from my part. There is a thing I have : To go fast you have to take it slow. (Usually shortcuts backfire and you spend more time debugging then actually going forward). Having said that : I applaud you for learning while also having a job :)  Keep learning keep asking questions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments. Don't translate code instead reimplement the algorithm.

Still your answer of this question.

**Conversion to python:**

```
def returnfac(n): 
    factorial=1
    
    if(n<0):
        print("Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.")
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            factorial*=i
       
        print("Factorial of",str(n),"=",str(factorial))    
        

if __name__=="__main__":
    returnfac(int(input("Enter a positive integer: ")))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a positive integer: 8
Factorial of 8 = 40320
```